# URL pattern matching in Android

Tags: android, deep-linking, android-instant-apps, url-pattern

I want my Instant App to catch a few links and discard rest. So below is the example of URL I want to catch:

https://www.example.com/myuser/login/?tc=AAAAAAQXDQAUFZNUUFWSFNNVE4=&next=/myuser/foo/some-other-parameter/foo1/593567297/&utm_source=gmail.com&utm_medium=email&etm_content=58475999468525d9bb3c365c840be5%7C%7C2018-05-02T00:25:26.381895%7CpdghXgghttX0G2iKafySwUTiIrLegggSqMfid/h3IDLrYmPnI38=%7C&utm_campaign=Custom

The pattern I made was:

```
<data
                android:scheme="https"
                android:host="www.example.com"
                android:pathPattern="myuser/login/..*/myuser/foo/..*"

                />
```

But this is not working.

Comment: You can't filter the query params (only the uri scheme/host/path)

Comment: So that means if i have urls with different query parameters, i wont be able to select which one to open and which one to discard?

Comment: Yes, you'll only be able to detect that after your receiver has been called.